# error about LLBLgen pro when run a asp.net file on localhost

Tags: llblgenpro

Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SD' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 25: using App2.DAL.ValidatorClasses;
Line 26: 
Line 27: using SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses;
Line 28: 
Line 29: namespace App2.DAL.EntityClasses

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Code\App2.DAL\DatabaseGeneric\EntityClasses\ListI9DocsEntity.cs    Line: 27

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your references to LLBLGen ORMSupportClasses assembly in your asp.net project. Make sure the dll is copied to the output /bin directory.

BTW, ask your questions on the LLBLGen Forums, as they are monitored every day by the support team.